# Function to free a struct in C

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, malloc, free

I'm having a problem where when I call a function I wrote to free a struct my program terminates on the first free instruction.

Here's the function:

```
void deleteJobNode(struct jobNode *node) {
    free(node->burstTime);
    free(node->jobIndex);
    free(node->next);
    free(node->priority);
    free(node->remainingTime);
    free(node);
}
```

Here is the definition of the struct and the function used to allocate memory to the struct.

```
struct jobNode {
    struct jobNode *next;
    int jobIndex;
    int burstTime;
    int remainingTime;
    int priority;
};

struct jobNode *createJobNode(int newJobIndex, int newBurstTime, int newRemainingTime, int newPriority) {
    struct jobNode *newNode = (struct jobNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct jobNode));
    newNode->jobIndex = newJobIndex;
    newNode->burstTime = newBurstTime;
    newNode->remainingTime = newRemainingTime;
    newNode->priority = newPriority;

    if(newNode == NULL)
        printf("Node Creation Error");

    return newNode;
}
```

I've edited the free function as suggested:

```
void deleteJobNode(struct jobNode *node) {
    free(node);
}
```

However I get this error at runtime:

```
*** Error in `/home/jack7521/workspace/req1b/Debug/req1b': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000010c2090 ***
```

Comment: Edited the code to as suggest, I still receive an error however

Comment: The error is probably elsewhere in your code.  Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You should check `malloc`s return value directly after you called it. Here you try to access the struct members to initialize them before you check if there was a null-pointer returned.

Comment: Also, try running your code under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org).

Answer (score 5):

You need a `free` for each `malloc`. You don't need to free non dynamic fields of a `struct`, they are already part of the `struct` itself so freeing the pointer to the whole `struct` is enough.

You just need:

```
free(node);
```

Comment: even you need not to call `free(bufptr->next)`, as it is supposed to be created in another call to `createJobNode`, so it will be freed twice if you call it for this node and the next.  Probably, the problem is actually here.

Answer (score 4):

You do **one** call to *malloc*; so why do you think you need **multiple** calls to *free*?!

Thing is: you only have to *free* that struct once - the final `free(node)` does the job!

Keep in mind what those methods do for you: *malloc* marks a contiguous memory area for use; and *free* gives up that **area**. There is no point in free'ing the members of your struct at all. Because they are *within* that area anyway.

Or from another angle: malloc gives you a bunch of bytes. The fact that you later use those bytes using that "struct" "overlay" isn't important at all!

Answer (score 0):

You only have to use `free` with the pointer to the struct instance.

```
void deleteJobNode(struct jobNode *node) {
  free(node); // will do the whole job
}
```

Because when you allocate some memory with a `malloc` call this is
one big bunch of memory which can then be released at once with `free`.

Only if your struct contains pointers which itself also point to some other dynamically allocated memory, you have to call `free` with these struct members.

Answer (score -1):

You are returning the address of a local variable (newNode) in 'createJobNode' function. newNode doesn't have any visibility outside the 'createJobNode' function. Try to allocate memory for the newNode in your main function and pass it as a parameter to the createJobNode (in this case it would be a void function) like this

```
void createJobNode(struct jobNode* newNode, ...)
{
     //Fill the fields of newNode

}

int main(void)
{
   struct jobNode * newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct newNode));

   createJobNode(newNode, ...);

}
```

To free the allocated variable newNode, you need to call:

```
free(newNode);
```

Comment: This answer is completely unrelated to the problem asked.

Comment: @Luis Colorado before commenting, users should read the question and answers properly. We are not here only to bring the appropriate answer to a question but also to rectify bad coding (like a C-function returning a local variable address).

Comment: you're right in the first sentence.  But flooding the normal answer beam with unrelated to the problem details with no contributing stuff deals to questions with no interest, if any, to anybody (even to the question asker)  This site is not only a forum where to ask to solve your problem, but problems serve for many people (not only the asker) to consult for actual real code.  Next time, if you are goint to point something unrelated to the problem, make it in the comments, not in the answer.  You will not get it downvoted.

Comment: And even your post is incorrect, you **can return** a non-visible variable reference from a function (making sure that it exists after function call, as when you declare it `static`), what you cannot return is a non-existent variable reference.

Comment: @Luis Colorado We do not bring answers for votes or reputation. It is not politics. Only those afraid of getting downvoted will comment instead of bringing answers. Each developper whether he is a beginner or an experienced guy should express his point of view upon a techinical question. As you said, the problem serve for many people, the next one who has a  similiar problem will copy this code and the others answers and he would get a runtime error. Look at the number of C-questions where the major problem is a C-function returning local reference.